What was meant by Holy Kiss?
We see Jesus being given a kiss twice in the Gospels: one in Lk 7:38 by the sinful woman on his feet, and the other by Judas Iscariot, most probably on the cheek. Jesus presumably kissed the feet of the Apostles after washing their feet on Last Supper, if the present day re-enactment of the event during the Holy Week reflected the ancient practice.

Both St. Peter and St. Paul exhorted the faithful to greet one another with the 'Holy Kiss' or 'Kiss of Love': as can be seen from Romans 16:16; 1 Corinthians 16:20; 2 Corinthians 13:12; 1 Thessalonians 5:26;  and 1 Peter 5:14.

It has been a Catholic tradition for the faithful to kiss the palm of the Bishop on his Pastoral Visit. Similarly, children kiss the palms of the elderly people of the family as a sign of respect.

Given that both St. Peter and St. Paul repeatedly exhorted the faithful to greet one another with the Holy Kiss, it is most likely that the tradition existed among Jesus and the disciples.


My question is: What was meant by Holy Kiss among early Christians and what was its origin?  Are there any ancient extra-biblical writings or modern scholarly material available on the topic?

"apocrypha" can imply writings that are heretical, although it can also mean pious writings not included in the canon.  To prevent heretical writings from being cited (such as the apocryphal gospels) I hope you don't mind me changing it to "extra biblical writings" that the early Christians could have written, as well as modern scholarly material on this topic.

You are most  welcome, GratefulDisciple.

It is clearly meant to be a chaste kiss.

cf. liturgical kiss of peace

What was meant by Holy Kiss?
The “Biblical” holy kiss is an ancient traditional Christian greeting, and is also called the kiss of peace and the kiss of charity and a kiss of peace.

It was the widespread custom in the ancient eastern Mediterranean for men to greet each other with a kiss. That was also the custom in ancient Judea and practiced also by Christians. However, the New Testament's references to a holy kiss (Ancient Greek: ἐν ἁγίω φιλήματι, en hagio philemati) and kiss of love (ἐν φιλήματι ἀγάπης) transformed the character of the act beyond a greeting; furthermore, in the early Church, "the verbal exchange of 'peace' with a kiss appears to be a Christian innovation, there being no clear example in pre-Christian literature." The holy kiss was thus followed as a biblical teaching, rather than a cultural tradition. Such a kiss is mentioned five times in the concluding section of
letters in the New Testament:

Romans 16:16—"Greet one another with a holy kiss" (Greek: ἀσπάσασθε ἀλλήλους ἐν φιλήματι ἁγίῳ).

1 Corinthians 16:20—"Greet one another with a holy kiss" (Greek: ἀσπάσασθε ἀλλήλους ἐν φιλήματι ἁγίῳ).

2 Corinthians 13:12—"Greet one another with a holy kiss" (Greek: ἀσπάσασθε ἀλλήλους ἐν ἁγίῳ φιλήματι).

1 Thessalonians 5:26—"Greet all the brothers with a holy kiss" (Greek: ἀσπάσασθε τοὺς ἀδελφοὺς πάντας ἐν φιλήματι ἁγίῳ).

1 Peter 5:14—"Greet one another with a kiss of love" (Greek: ἀσπάσασθε ἀλλήλους ἐν φιλήματι ἀγάπης).


The early Christian apologist Tertullian wrote that before leaving a house, Christians are to give the holy kiss and say "peace to this house".  Justin Martyr, Origen, and Cyprian attested to the practice of the holy kiss among Christians as well.
Though also, practiced outside of church, since the aforementioned epistles were addressed to Christian communities, the practice of the holy kiss was especially relevant in communal worship. It has been noted that these mentions of the holy kiss come at the end of these epistles, indicating "that the kiss was shared in conjunction with the benedictions at the conclusion of worship services" though it soon "became associated with the Eucharist" and thus "its location during the worship service moved forward in time to the celebration of Communion." The holy kiss was seen as an essential part of preparing to partake in the Eucharist:

Peace, reconciliation, and unity were the very essence of the church's life; without them communion would have been a sham. Bestowed by the Spirit and experienced in prayer, their liturgical expression—which pointed forward to the eucharist—was the holy kiss.

For the early Christians, the holy kiss "was associated with the peace and unity given by the Holy Spirit to the congregation."
The writings of the early church fathers speak of the holy kiss, which they call "a sign of peace", which was already part of the Eucharistic liturgy, occurring after the Lord's Prayer in the Roman Rite and the rites directly derived from it. St. Augustine, for example, speaks of it in one of his Easter Sermons:

Then, after the consecration of the Holy Sacrifice of God, because He wished us also to be His sacrifice, a fact which was made clear when the Holy Sacrifice was first instituted, and because that Sacrifice is a sign of what we are, behold, when the Sacrifice is finished, we say the Lord's Prayer which you have received and recited. After this, the 'Peace be with you' is said, and the Christians embrace one another with the holy kiss. This is a sign of peace; as the lips indicate, let peace be made in your conscience, that is, when your lips draw near to those of your brother, do not let your heart withdraw from his. Hence, these are great and powerful sacraments.

Augustine's Sermon 227 is just one of several early Christian primary sources, both textual and iconographic (i.e., in works of art) providing clear evidence that the "kiss of peace" as practiced in the Christian liturgy was customarily exchanged for the first several centuries, not mouth to cheek, but mouth to mouth (note that men were separated from women during the liturgy) for, as the primary sources also show, this is how early Christians believed Christ and his followers exchanged their own kiss. For example, in his Paschale carmen (c. 425–50), Latin priest-poet Sedulius condemns Judas and his betrayal of Christ with a kiss thus, "And leading that sacrilegious mob with its menacing swords and spikes, you press your mouth against his, and infuse your poison into his honey?" - Holy Kiss

This religious practice (Holy Kiss) of a sign of peace remains a part of the worship in traditional churches, including the Roman Catholic Church, Eastern Catholic Churches, Eastern Orthodox Churches, Oriental Orthodox Churches, the Church of the East; the Lutheran Church, and the Anglican Church, where it is often called the kiss of peace, sign of peace, holy kiss or simply sign peace or pax.
In the Catholic Church the Kiss of Peace is of ancient origin. From a very early date, in the East and the West women and men were separated in the assemblies of the faithful, and the kiss of peace was given only by women to women and by men to men. Then in about the twelfth or thirteenth century the use of the instrumentum pacis, or osculatorium, known in English as the "pax-board" or "pax-brede", was gradually introduced. This was a little plaque of metal, ivory, or wood, generally decorated with some pious carving and provided with a handle, which was first brought to the altar for the celebrant to kiss at the proper place in the Mass and then brought to each of the congregation in turn at the altar rails. But even this practice in course of time died out, and at the present day the Pax is only given at High Mass, and is hardly anywhere communicated to the congregation.
Apostolic Constitutions declared: "Then let the men apart, and the women apart, salute each other with a kiss in the Lord."
The following articles may be of interest to some:

The Holy Kiss

What exactly is a holy kiss?

Kiss (Catholic Encyclopaedia)


